# Creating Paypal Recurring Payments between other enterprise and user

Tags: express, paypal, payment, checkout, recurring

We develop a management system for other companies with which they receive online payments with Paypal. For single payments we have successfully implemented Adaptive Express Checkout, so that the money goes directly from the user account to the company account.

But now we are trying to implement Recurring Payments in the same way. I've research hundreds of forum threads and official documentation and I couldn't find a guide to achieve this. Some people say that it's impossible to create Recurring Payments on other Companies behalf.

However, I discover there is a specific permission in Profile->Api Access->Api permissions section who says: "Create and manage Recurring Payments". If one Business Account gives this permission to my api account I should be able to do it, BUT HOW?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i did similar recurring payment for my company website. Basically i created a subscription payment button and added them to the webpage. It was very straight forward to set up in paypal website. I did initially in their sandbox environment and tested whether it works.

Does your requirement allow you to have payment buttons? in that case it would make your life easy.

Comment: I tried that solution, but in that case we don't have the permission to edit the recurring payment profile in the future. 
I think it should be possible to do it through Express Checkout because as I said, the special permission exists.